# Using PHP in <script> tag?

Tags: php, javascript, json, object

I'm trying to create an object in javascript with PHP. This is my script:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var genres = [
    <?php
    $last = count($userGenres) - 1;
    $i = 0;
    foreach($userGenres as $a){
        $i++;
        echo '{"value":"'.$a['genre'].'", "name":"'.$a['name'].'"}';
        if($i < $last){
            echo ',';
        }
    }
    ?>
                        ];
   });
</script>
```

When I check the generated source, it creates a valid object, but the whole script in that tag doesn't work now. How would fix this, without JSON?

Thanks

Comment: You didn't close the `$(document).ready()` function.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What is the problem?

Comment: Where is this code hosted? In a PHP file I guess?

Comment: Are you aware of the `json_encode()` function in PHP?

Comment: Can you show the generated script?

Comment: You should **really** use `json_encode`. Otherwise your code is quite brittle as-is.

Comment: A better approach might be to make an object in php, and then json encode it

Comment: This isn't exactly an answer to your question but I am guessing `$userGenres` is an array? and in your `foreach() loop` you are incrementing `$i` before anything else so aren't you going to be missing the first value of the array? or is that intentional?

Comment: Problem is in the final iteration, due to i++ being at the top, I already posted it as a reply

Comment: @Grega Menih did this solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment says you should consider using (php function)json_encode instead, which will turn...

```
php:

$a = array(
  array("gender"=> "male", "name"=> "Bob"),
  array("gender"=> "female", "name"=> "Annie")
);

Into json:
[
   {gender:"male", name:"Bob"},
   {gender:"female", name:"Annie"}
]
```

Echoing json_encode($a) would output it just like that.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to close the `.ready()` method and the anonymous function inside of it.

Try this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var genres = [
            <?php
            $last = count($userGenres) - 1;
            $i = 0;
            foreach($userGenres as $a)
            {
                $i++;
                echo '{"value":"'.$a['genre'].'", "name":"'.$a['name'].'"}';
                if($i < $last)
                {
                    echo ',';
                }
            }
            ?>
        ];
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not closed properly:

```
}
    }
    ?>
                        ];
}); // <--- add this
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var genres = [
            <?php
            $last = count($userGenres) - 1;
            $i = 0;
            foreach($userGenres as $a)
            {
                echo '{"value":"'.$a['genre'].'", "name":"'.$a['name'].'"}';
                if($i < $last)
                {
                    echo ',';
                }

                $i++;
            }
            ?>
        ];
    });
</script>
```

**Changes:** You have to close the anonymous function and the ready() method. Also, move the i++ to the end so that you cover all cases (you will be missing one). The error you get is because you have the i++ wrong.